# Error: el ejecutable dejó de funcionar y devuelve error 255

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema al momento de correr el programa me sale un mensaje ".exe dejo de funcionar" y me retorna 255.

Es un ejemplo de colas circulares, pero al momento de compilar y ejecutar me salen los errores mostrados en las imágenes abajo:

```
// colas circulares

 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class colaCircular{
    private:
        int frente; // frente de la cola 
        int maximo; //capacidad de la cola
        int n;      //numero de elementos
        int cola[]; // vector cola
    public:
        // constructor
        colaCircular(int tamanio){
            this->maximo =tamanio; // define la capacidad
            this->cola[tamanio]=cola[tamanio]; //crea el espacio en la cola
            this->frente=0; // inicializa el frente en 0
            this->n=0;  // inicio de la variable numero de elementos
        };

        void entradaElemento(int dato){
         // si la cola circular esta llena 
         if (n==maximo){
            cout<<" cola llena "<<endl;

         }  
         else {
         // nueva ubicacion del dato 
         int ubicacion = (frente + n)%maximo;
         cola[ubicacion]=dato; // se ingresa el dato
         cout <<" Frente "<<frente<<"\t"<<" n "<<n<<"\t"<<"maximo "<<maximo<<"\t ubicacion "<<ubicacion<<endl;
         n++; // se incrementa n

         }
        };

        int salidaElemnto(){
        // sale el elemento del frente
         int aux =cola[frente];
         cout<<" sale el elemento "<<aux;
         frente = (frente+1)%maximo;
         n--;
         cout<<" frente "<<frente<<"\t"<<"n  "<<n<<endl;
         return 0;

        };

 };

 int main (){
    colaCircular objCir(10);
    // ingresar datos
    objCir.entradaElemento(1);
    objCir.entradaElemento(2);
    objCir.entradaElemento(3);
    objCir.entradaElemento(4);
    objCir.entradaElemento(5);
    objCir.entradaElemento(6);
    // sacar datos 
    objCir.salidaElemnto();
    objCir.salidaElemnto();
    objCir.salidaElemnto();
    // volver a ingresar datos
    objCir.entradaElemento(7);
    objCir.entradaElemento(8);
    objCir.entradaElemento(9);
    objCir.entradaElemento(10);
    objCir.entradaElemento(11);
    objCir.entradaElemento(12);
    objCir.entradaElemento(13);
    return 0;
};
```

[image: EL ERROR QUE ME MUESTRA]

[image: EL VALOR DE RETORNO]

Comment: Hace mucho tiempo que no trabajo con C/C++, pero te diría que el problema es que no está reservando la memoria correctamente (aquí: `this->cola[tamanio]=cola[tamanio];` donde realmente lo que estarías haciendo es acceder a la posición `tamanio` –que no ha sido reservada– y darle el valor de `cola[tamanio]`) y eso hace que en algún momento accedas a alguna posición que no te corresponde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se qué compilador estarás usando, pero un compilador contemporáneo no permite crear formaciones<sup>1</sup> sin tamaño en un objeto:

```
class colaCircular{
   private:
       int frente;
       int maximo;
       int n;
       int cola[]; // ¡¡ERROR!! Falta el tamaño.
```

Si quieres tener un tamaño dinámico, usa un `std::vector`:

```
class colaCircular{
   private:
       int frente; // frente de la cola 
       int maximo; //capacidad de la cola
       int n;      //numero de elementos
       std::vector<int> cola; // vector cola
   public:
       // constructor
       colaCircular(int tamanio){
           // El 'this' es innecesario.
           maximo = tamanio;
           cola.resize(tamanio);
           frente = 0;
           n = 0;
       };

    // ...
    // ...
};
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda compila correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Esta instrucción provoca el error:

```
this->cola[tamanio]=cola[tamanio]; //crea el espacio en la cola
```

Creo que debería ser:

```
this->cola = new int[tamanio];
```